# how to Proxypass to different server with same context

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-proxy, proxypass

i want to redirect to multiple servers from a single server which is enables httpd.

I tried like this

```
ProxyPass "/qa170901" "http://hostname1:8080/appc"
ProxyPass "/patch1801" "http://hostname2:8080/appc"
```

I even tried like

```
Proxypass "/qa171201/appc/" "http://hostname3:8080/appc/"
ProxyPassReverse "/qa171201/appc/" "http://hostname3:8080/appc/"

Proxypass "/patch171101" "http://hostname4:9090/appc"
Proxypass "/qa171101" "http://hostname4:8080/appc"
```

but nothing seems working

Comment: Does it work with only one server?

Comment: @DusanBajic
  I am having apache in one server, 
lets say hostname
and want to redirect using this hostname and specific url pattern to
lik 
/r1 to hostname1:8080/appc
/r2 to hostname2:9090/appc